# Finding the probability distribution of a function of two random varialbes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

A game consists of two phases.

The first phase requires the player to throw two darts at an objective and each throw is either a score or a miss. It is known that three out every ten players scores at least once. Let $Z$ be the random variable that model the number of scores (either zero, one or two).

In the next phase of the game, you pick $Z$ balls from an urn containing five balls (this is done without replacement). Two of the balls are labelled "2", two balls are labelled "1", and one ball is labelled "3". Let $W$ be the sum of the Z labels. Find the distribution of $W$.

What I've done so far is determine that $Z$ has a Bernoulli distribution with mean $ p = 0.1633$ and $n=2$, and I know that $W$ is a function of $Z$ but I'm clueless about how to find the distribution of $W$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find $P(W=w)$ for each $w=0,1,\dots,5$. To do this, condition on the value of $Z$:
$$
P(W=w)=P(W=w|Z=0)P(Z=0)+P(W=w|Z=1)P(Z=1)+P(W=w|Z=2)P(Z=2)
$$
You know how to find all of the quantities $P(Z=z)$ for $z=0,1,2$, so all that remains are the conditional probabilities.

$P(W=w|Z=0)$ is $1$ when $w=0$ and $0$ otherwise, since $W$ is certainly zero when $Z$ is zero.

$P(W=w|Z=1)$ is given by the below table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
w & 1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
P(W=w) & 2/5 & 2/5 & 1/5
\end{array}
$$

$P(W=w|Z=2)$ is a little messier, but can be found by enumerating all 10 ways of choosing two of the five balls from the urn and seeing what the total is in each case.